# While using XML based configuration in Spring MVC Project getting null from @Autowired beans

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to develop Spring MVC Project using XML based configuration. I have created one controller class and trying to access POJO class through @Autowire. But I am getting null object if I declare bean manually. If I am using component-scan then it is working fine. Not able to identify what I am missing in first approach.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/service-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

service-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

</beans>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
    
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
    <!-- This isn't working
      <bean id = "restCtrl" class = "org.Test.RestCtrl"></bean>
      <bean id = "person" class="org.Test.Person">
        <property name="name" value="ABC"></property>
        <property name="age" value = "22"></property>
      </bean>
    </beans> -->
    // This is working
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.Test"/>
```

Person.java

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public int getAge() { return age; }
    public void setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }
}
```

RestCtrl.java

```
@RestController
public class RestCtrl {
    @Autowired
    Person person;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/health", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String health(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println(person); // returning null
        return "OK"; // getting OK in browser
    }   
}
```

Comment: don't you need @Component for Person?

Comment: Tried with @Component also for Person class still getting null and is it required to put annotations with XML based configuration as well?

Comment: I _think_ you might need request scope in your XML controller bean. But I also think trying to use that XML approach for MVC objects will prove more pain than it's worth. Why don't you want to use component scanning? (We generally use annotations and component scanning for the MVC objects specifically, putting them in their own Java package, and XML for the non-MVC ones.)